# SQL server in networks

Tags: sql-server

a network consists of a lot of servers like web server, DNS server, FTP server , ... but i confused about SQL server. SQL server is used to store data.

1. my first question: is SQL server a separate server in network and a
   host is dedicated to run SQL server and other servers like DNS
   server, Web server, ... query to it to store and fetch their data?
   or not there is not any dedicated host to SQL server but other
   servers in network like DNS server, Web server, ... also run SQL
   server and store their own data locally in SQL server?
2. my second question: some part of internet traffic is because of SQL 
   server (queries to SQL server and responses from SQL server). who
   query to SQL server? is clients query to SQL server? or is web
   servers, FTP server, ... query to SQL server? i think if SQL server 
   is hosted in servers of network (Web server, DNS server, ...) so any
   traffic should not generate because of SQL server because queries is
   done locally

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: why negative score???!!! I ask question. I have problem but you give me negative score instead of helping me. sorry for you

Answer (score 0):

1. Technically a SQL server maybe a dedicates server or just a service running on a host concurrent with other services, so both are possible, but if there is SQL traffic it seems the first case is more plausible for your network.
2. Usally another service queries or stores data on an SQL Server, user interaction is seldom. An example would be a database containing users running on the SQL server queried by the webserver to see if the client(user) authentificating to the webserver is allowed to do so.

Comment: thanks for your help. in the second case, how that service communicate with SQL server? via port? for example imagine a web server that running SQL server and saves its data on that. how this web server communicate with SQL server? are them communicate via port?

Answer (score 0):

I hope these quick points help clarify things:

- Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL) is Microsoft's longstanding, flagship Relational Database Management Systems (RDBMS) product.
- MSSQL is an engine that can run on a dedicate Microsoft Windows Server deployment, on a system hosting other roles (not recommended), or in the cloud (Microsoft Azure SQL).
- MSSQL's implementation of ANSI standardized SQL is called Transact-SQL (T-SQL).
- While most servers and applications store their data in a RDBMS, there are many options besides MSSQL and options outside of RDBMS altogether, such as NoSQL.
- MSSQL communicates via standard TCP/IP port traffic, must commonly being TCP port 1433.
- MSSQL offers various other services to extend the RDBMS, such as SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS), which typically communicate via their own TCP/IP ports.
- You asked about Domain Name System (DNS); this typically runs on a flat file database, such as NoSQL.
- Other well known systems, such as Active Directory and/or Microsoft Exchange Server, run on proprietary databases, such as Microsoft's Joint Engine Technology (JET) Blue and Red databases.